# allowing anonymous user to save contents of a form in sharepoint doc library

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, save, sharepoint-2007, anonymous-users

I have moss 2007 configured for anonymous access. I also have a public accessible form created in infopath, which can be opened in a webpage and filled and submitted. However, an anonymous user is unable to submit the form after filling it. Submit action is supposed to save the form in a doucment library.

I checked the anonymous permission for this document library(settings>permissions>Anonymous access) and see that only "View Items" is enabled while other options to "Add Items" or "Edit Items" has been disabled and greyed out.

Is there a way how an anonymous user can fill out a form and its contents can be submitted in a document library in sharepoint?

Comment: After much googling, it seems Sharepoint doesn't allow Anonymous users to add to a document library. It allows the same for Lists and Surveys, but not to a document library.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround. See
http://blog.metrostarsystems.com/2009/06/04/anonymously-submit-infopath-form-to-sharepoint-library/